# Webpack compiling throwing error with mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, mobx

I am using webpack as module bundler and babel for transpiling.
My current npm version is 3.10.9 and node version is v6.9.2.

Package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "compression": "^1.6.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "csslint": "^1.0.5",
    "csslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "express": "^4.9.8",
    "express-https-redirect": "^1.0.0",
    "express-manifest": "^0.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.9",
    "less": "^3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss": "^6.0.13",
    "postcss-css-variables": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss-mixins": "^6.1.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^2.1.2",
    "postcss-start-to-end": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-doc-generator": "^1.2.5",
    "react-docgen-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.28",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^1.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "stylelint": "^8.2.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webfonts-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "wrapper-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expres": "0.0.5",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-minify-html": "^0.11.5",
    "html-minifier": "^3.5.6",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "mobx": "^3.0.0",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.0",
    "pa11y-ci": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
    ]
  },
```

when I compile I get below issue.

```js
Using default export (`import mobx from 'mobx'`) is deprecated and wont work in mobx@4.0.0
Use `import * as mobx from 'mobx'` instead
D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41
    throw new Constructor(this._buildMessage(msg));
    ^

ReferenceError: [BABEL] D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\webpack.config.babel.js: Unknown option: base.Reaction. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.
```

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

```js
Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options.
    at Logger.error (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:226:20)
    at OptionManager.init (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at Object.transformFileSync (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\node.js:152:10)
    at compile (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:118:20)
    at loader (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
```

Please help.

Comment: so ... did you follow the clear instructions in the error?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, but no help.

Comment: so, what did you change in `D:\mgm\dmp\fe-react\webpack.config.babel.js`

Comment: note: the first "error" is just a warning (for now) - the issue is `Unknown option: base.Reaction`

Comment: webpack config. {test: /.js?$/,exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['env', {
                                modules: false,
                                targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'safari >= 7', 'ie >= 10'] }
                            }], 'stage-0', 'react'
                        ],
                        comments:true
                    }
                }]
            },

Comment: is that what you changed from, or what you changed to?

Comment: Nope it is same. just installed mobx and mob-react dependencies.

Comment: so, after you got the error, with explanation of what you need to change, you changed nothing ... there's details in the error that only you can address as you haven't shown the file that has the problem in the question

Answer (score 1):

First things first, remove mobx presets from your `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": ["mobx"]
}
```

then `npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` and add below `.babelrc` configration.

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "env", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy", // must on the top of plugins array.
    ... ...
  ]
}
```

finally, you must delete `babel-preset-mobx` that 0 start on the GitHub, I think it's unstable.